# Encrypted Home Directory Problems/Questions

Tags: home, ecryptfs

I usually use full disk encryption but I want to create a Ubuntu server that multiple user can use as a file server (using SSHFS GUI clients) and therefore I want their home directories to be encrypted when they are not logged on.

- I installed Ubuntu 16.04.  I installed `ecryptfs-utils` and `cryptsetup`.
- I typed `ecryptfs-migrate-home -u <username>`
- Then I logged in as `<username>`.
- Then I typed `touch filename`.
- Then I logged out as `<username>`.
- Then as root I did `ls /home/<username>`.

And I saw `filename`!  But root should not be able to see this because the directory should be encrypted.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: LUKS containers mounted as loop devices can only be unlocked by those with the key. Have those mount on login with the user's own keys and automagically unmount and close on logout. I can't tell you how to do it, so I'm posting this as a comment instead of an answer. ^_^;

Comment: @miorlin That is what I thought I did and yet it does not work so that is why I am posting here.

Answer (score -1):

Root can always see encrypted files/folders. There are a few ways to hide your activities from a root users but with a little bit of effort a root user can still find it. Root sees all. You should be the only one on the system with root access anyway so it shouldn't matter too much in your situation.

Comment: ps. even though root can see the encrypted folder it still cant access the contents without the crypt key.

Comment: *Not* seeing encrypted files within the folder is the expected result but what actually happens is what I described in my post.  Can you explain why?